# How to get joined data from two tables that have one-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myDB`.`trips` (
  `IdTrip` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `IsCancelled` TINYINT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdTrip`) );

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myDB`.`stats` (
  `IdStat` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `IdTrip` INT NOT NULL ,
  `DateStat` DATE NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdStat`) ,
  INDEX `fk_trips_stats_idx` (`IdTrip` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_trips_stats`
    FOREIGN KEY (`IdTrip` )
    REFERENCES `myDB`.`trip` (`IdTrip` )
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE RESTRICT);
```

The relation is one-to-many: one trip may have different stats.

Now I want to show all information about trips that have MORE THAN 1 entry in `stats` for the period (defined by DateStat) from `'2015-05-01'` till `'2015-05-25'`.

If there would be one-to-one relationship, then I would check the date this way:

```
DateStat BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-25'
```

But I have no idea how to make it for the one-to-many relationship, while also considering the number of stats per a trip.

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

Comment: @jarlh: Could you please explain it in the answer? Thanks.

Comment: aren't you missing a field in stats? (IdTrip) ? I see the FK but where did you defined it in the table.

Comment: @John: Yes, sorry, it is a typo error. IdRide -> IdTrip

Answer (score 3):

Simple `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` should be enough:

```
SELECT
    trips.IdTrip
    ,trips.IsCancelled
FROM
    trips
    INNER JOIN stats ON stats.IdTrip = trips.IdTrip
WHERE
    stats.DateStat >= '2015-09-01 00:00:00' 
    AND stats.DateStat < '2015-09-26 00:00:00'
GROUP BY
    trips.IdTrip
    ,trips.IsCancelled
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/739ad/5/0) with your sample data. I changed the range of dates in the query to September to include your sample data. If you set range of dates in the query to May as in the question, the query would return no rows, because there are now rows for May in the data.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason it returns an empty set. Could you please show it with SQL fiddle?

Comment: @KlausosKlausos, please provide some sample data, preferably in SQL fiddle. I can put together some random numbers and dates, of course, but it would be better if you gave us an example that you are working with and having problems with.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos, first step to check what's wrong would be to remove the `HAVING` clause and add `COUNT(*)` to `SELECT` part and check the results. Maybe you indeed don't have any trips that satisfy the criteria.

Comment: Here you have a link to SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/739ad
The query should return just a single entry with IdTrip=1.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos, I added fiddle to my answer. Your sample data has rows with dates in September, so I adjusted range of dates in the query to include September. If you set range of dates in the query to May, it would return no rows.